# How can I specify Argo workflow multiple output artifacts to a single directory?

Tags: argo-workflows

I'm using Argo Workflow, and want to produce 2 separate artifacts. Defining the output artifacts as below, it tells me `path '/tmp' already mounted in inputs.artifacts.txt`. How can I mount produce 2 separate artifacts to a single directory(in this case, `/tmp`)?

```yaml
outputs:
  artifacts:
  - name: txt
    path: /tmp
    s3:
      endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
      bucket: <My Bucket>
      key: test.txt.tgz
      accessKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_access_key-0
      secretKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_secret_key-0
  - name: total-file-count
    path: /tmp
    s3:
      endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
      bucket: <My Bucket>
      key: total-file-count.tgz
      accessKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_access_key-0
      secretKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_secret_key-0
```

Answer (score 1):

`path` refers to the full path of the artifact to be written to S3 (not just to the directory in which the file is found).

To write both artifacts to S3, use the full path of the source files. Assuming the filenames match the key names, this should work:

```yaml
outputs:
  artifacts:
  - name: txt
    path: /tmp/test.txt.tgz
    s3:
      endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
      bucket: <My Bucket>
      key: test.txt.tgz
      accessKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_access_key-0
      secretKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_secret_key-0
  - name: total-file-count
    path: /tmp/total-file-count.tgz
    s3:
      endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
      bucket: <My Bucket>
      key: total-file-count.tgz
      accessKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_access_key-0
      secretKeySecret:
        name: vault-data
        key: s3_secret_key-0
```